# How to make an alternating value in a single cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to make a cell swap between two values every couple of seconds, but I don't know how.

EX: A1=1, then a second later A1=0, then a second later A1=1, and it repeats like that, does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: see if this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60926427/how-do-i-call-google-script-triggers-every-second

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GeY4rbkM4ylHUZhT8kMiMXd0vN_R793175381gX3Jks/edit#gid=0) sheet show how change A1 from 0 to 1 and vice versa every minute

Comment: From what I see, it only shows the alternating cell (A1) and a few comments in column C, it does not show any tutorial explaining how to replicate the script. Could you edit the sheet to better show how to replicate the script?

Comment: @Sebastian
 First you'll have to copy the script in your google sheet. While you are in the app script window you will notice an icon in the shape of an alarm clock, click on it and you will be able to understand how the trigger was set up and then how to replicate it.